# Kanban - Calculating using Little's Law?

Tags: engineering, kanban

I need some help in answering this question

[image: Kanban Figure]

Some Info on the diagram

- On the left it says "Your wait time from here is about 14/18 days"
- The numbers at the bottom of the columns are the maximum number of
  Kanban cards allowed in each column

[Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law) states that:

> The long-term average number of customers in a stable system L is equal to the long-term average effective arrival rate, λ, multiplied by the ([Palm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_calculus)‑)average time a customer spends in the system, W; or expressed algebraically: L = λW.

Using the image, I'm trying to calculate the average time for a story to get from the top of the Story queue to “Done” (i.e. the cycle time) if the average processing rate is two stories per day in each column.

I have tried doing 14/2, assuming that the question means the literal top of the queue, but was unsure.

Comment: How can you assume that the average processing rate is two stories per day in each column if it takes 14 days for one story to move through 5 columns? Unless it has to do with the WIP limits. Also, are you considering the average time a story takes in the Story Queue? If the top story takes 14 days to move through the system and the bottom story would take 18, isn't the average time in the system 16 days?

Comment: I'm curious... Do you grab stories from the top of the column or the bottom?  Because if you're grabbing it from the top, doesn't that mean you have to move all of the other sticky notes to the top to fill in the void?